# How can I capture an audio stream playing in my application, and then it use it as a valid input for Web Audio API for visualization?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, audio-streaming, web-audio-api

I am building an app that I want to be able to capture browser audio from say Spotify or YT. And then make it so that I can turn it into a live stream to input into Web Audio API to create visuals while the audio plays. I've came across technologies like Jack and MediaCapture API but wanted to know if anyone has an efficient approach. Any ideas and suggestions are appreciated greatly.

UPDATE:

Was able to get my audio to stream in my application's tab. I am looking for an approach on how to capture the audio to analyze it. I've seen a method where it can be captured through microphone hardware, but I wanted to capture just the audio without any interfering noises.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`getDisplayMedia()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getDisplayMedia) to get a MediaStream from other tabs, but this is subject to browser support.  Chromium-based browsers support this, but others are less compatible at the moment.

Additionally, the UX isn't very good.  It depends on the user first choosing that they want to capture another tab, checking a box to share that tab's audio, and then continuing.  Also, you need to then stop the video track you get back.

You might consider participating in these discussions to push for better browser support:

- https://github.com/w3c/mediacapture-screen-share/issues/100
- https://github.com/w3c/mediacapture-viewport/issues/11

Comment: Appreciate this info, although UX wouldn't be nice, would still be something worth experimenting. Since, I posted this though, I was able to get my audio stream playing on my app's tab. My struggle right now is capturing that audio stream from the current tab, to be able to analyze it.